# R and text on Cyrillic

Tags: r

I am trying to save text он Cyrillic in an R script, but I am encountering a problem. Specifically, when I save it with encoding UTF-8, everything appears fine. However, after closing the script and reopening it, I notice some unreadable characters. See below:

```
df<-     
               list("00OÃÂ¿ÃÂÃÂÃÂ¸ÃÂ½ÃÂ¸"=c("0000","0019","0094","0108","0027","0035","0043","0051","0116","0060","0078","0086","1015","1040","1066","1082","1104","1139","1147","1155","1163","1171","1180","1201","1236","1279","1287","1295","1309","1031","1325","1333","1341","2097","1376","1392","1422","1457","1473","1481","1490","1511","1520","1562","1597","1619","1627","1635","1643","1678","1694","1708","1724","1732","1759","1783","1805","1821","1830","1899","1902","1929","1937","1953","1961","1970","1988","1996","2003","2046","2054","2127","2135","2143","2151","2160","2178","2208","2216","2232","2259","2283"),
                     "ÃÂÃÂ¾ÃÂ´ÃÂ¸ÃÂ½ÃÂ°"=c("22"),
                     "ÃÂÃÂºÃÂÃÂ¿ÃÂ½ÃÂ¾ ÃÂ¿ÃÂ¾ÃÂÃÂ°ÃÂ½ÃÂµÃÂÃÂ½ÃÂ° ÃÂ´ÃÂÃÂ¶ÃÂ°ÃÂ²ÃÂ°"=c("000"),
                     "ÃÂÃÂÃÂ£ÃÂÃÂÃÂ"=c("000","070","705","688","499","191","910","008","100","792","001","999"))
```

Can anybody help how to solve this problem and to keep text in Cyrillic ?

Comment: Is this problem affected by whether or not you run this code? This doesn't sound like an R question. Seems to be an issue with whatever text editor or IDE you're using.

Comment: Provide `sessionInfo()` and which IDE and version you are using if any.